# How to use React-redux to avoid local state in my code?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux and I have put up a simple code which uses the store, action and reducer. I am using store.subscribe() to listen for changes in the state and using it to update my local state.

Below is my entire code in index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

var store = createStore(changeState);
var initialState = {
    qty: 0,
    price: 0
}

function changeState(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            var stateCopy1 = Object.assign({}, state);
            stateCopy1.qty = stateCopy1.qty + action.qty;
            stateCopy1.price = stateCopy1.price + action.price;
            return stateCopy1;
        default:
            return state;

    }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Comp1 /><br />
                <Comp2 />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
    increase = () => {
        var action = {
            type: 'INCREMENT',
            qty: 1,
            price: 100
        }
        store.dispatch(action);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.increase}>Increase</button>
        )
    }

}
class Comp2 extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cartQty: 0,
            cartPrice: 0
        }
    }
    render() {
        store.subscribe(() => {
            var globalState = store.getState();
            this.setState({cartQty:globalState.qty,cartPrice:globalState.price});
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Total items in cart: {this.state.cartQty}</h1>
                <h1>Total price of cart :{this.state.cartPrice}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I want to use react-redux to avoid the local state and subscription. I read about connect() and mapStateToProps() and . But I am unable to figure out how to use them in my below code. How can I implement these parts in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things that you need to take care of.

**First**, you need to have a react-redux installed and then use Provider component at the top level to which you pass store

**Second**: You need to connect the components that need to access `store` or `dispatch`

**Third**: You need to render the connected components

**Fourth**: You need `mapStateToProps` to be passed to container which access state and `mapDispatchToProps` to accesses dispatch or make action creators available as props to components. In case you do not pass `mapDispatchToProps` to `connect`, by default `dispatch` prop is made available to the component. You can look at the **[API docs here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch)**

**Fifth** Create store after defining changeState reducer and initialState

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'

var initialState = {
    qty: 0,
    price: 0
}

function changeState(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            var stateCopy1 = Object.assign({}, state);
            stateCopy1.qty = stateCopy1.qty + action.qty;
            stateCopy1.price = stateCopy1.price + action.price;
            return stateCopy1;
        default:
            return state;

    }
}

var store = createStore(changeState);

class Comp1 extends React.Component {
    increase = () => {
        var action = {
            type: 'INCREMENT',
            qty: 1,
            price: 100
        }
        this.props.dispatch(action);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.increase}>Increase</button>
        )
    }

}
const Comp1Container = connect()(Comp1);

class Comp2 extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Total items in cart: {this.props.cartQty}</h1>
                <h1>Total price of cart :{this.props.cartPrice}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return  {
      cartQty:state.qty,
      cartPrice: state.price
   }
}
const Comp2Container = connect(mapStateToProps)(Comp2);


class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Comp1Container /><br />
                <Comp2Container />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Home /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko3z83yxxv)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess const Comp2Container = connect(mapStateToProps) should be const Comp2Container = connect(mapStateToProps)(Comp2)? Also, I get state as undefined in the mapStateToProps function.

Comment: @codingSplash, did you use Provider component and passed store to it

Comment: Yes. I did use a provider component and pass the store to it

Comment: Updated the answer and added a demo, you need to createStore after defining the reducer and initial state otherwise it will be undefined at the time of creation

Comment: Thanks. Now the error is gone, but when I click on the button, nothing happens. You can find my code here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/x2zm26rv34

Comment: This is because in the mapStateToProps function instead of defining cartQty and cartPrice, you have defined, qty and price. The object keys returned by mapStateToProps must be the same the properties used from props in the component

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can, first let's make sure concepts are clear.

Redux already has a 'state', so you copying it to your internal state is redundant.

`connect()`:
This convenience  method is used to map the redux's state, to props in your component. That is, you're not copying the state into another state, you use Redux's state as props, which are inmutable and more like a reference to the real data inside Redux.
It's built with a pattern call [hoc](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), but that's a lesson for another question. The important thing to know about a hoc is that it takes a component as an argument and it returns a new component, an improved one.

`mapStateToProps()`:
This will be your way into telling `connect` what part of redux's state you want to get inside your component. It's a method that receives the complete redux's state, extracts the properties you want to use, and returns them to be sent as props to your component.

Now you're missing one key part of the ecuation here, which is redux's...
`Provider`:
This piece should wrap all of your app ( or the part of it that you want it to has redux access, which usually is all of it ) and is the one in charge of sending redux's store down the tree so `connect` can grab it later ( This is achieved through react's [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), but that's a meal for another date ).
You get your provider like: `import {Provider} from 'react-redux';` and then you give it the store as a prop called.... `store` (clever right?)

Enough chit chat right, let's get down to business.

We start with the imports, let's get everything we need:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
```

We added two more things here the `Provider` component and the `connect` hoc.

```
var initialState = {
    qty: 0,
    price: 0
}

function changeState(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            var stateCopy1 = Object.assign({}, state);
            stateCopy1.qty = stateCopy1.qty + action.qty;
            stateCopy1.price = stateCopy1.price + action.price;
            return stateCopy1;
        default:
            return state;

    }
}
var store = createStore(changeState);
```

Now, you saw what happened there? Exactly! Nothing. Your reducer can remain as is, we are not moving that, although for a larger app you may want to learn to [combine reducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Comp1 /><br />
                <Comp2 />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Ok, your `Fragment` is gone, I'm sorry about that, but it's now no longer necessary. `Fragment`s are used to return two or more components, but since the `Provider` is now wrapping the components, there is no need to use a `Fragment`.
And about the `Provider`, you just need to put it outside of everything and give it your `store`. Easy enough.

```
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
    increase = () => {
        var action = {
            type: 'INCREMENT',
            qty: 1,
            price: 100
        }
        store.dispatch(action);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.increase}>Increase</button>
        )
    }

}
```

In this last component we didn't move anything. Although we should have, look how you're using your `store` directly to `dispatch` your `action`. In a normal app, this component would be in another file, so you wouldn't have access to the `store` property. And here comes again our friend `connect` which helps us dispatch actions through a function called `mapDispatchToProps` you read about it [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch), but that's also for another day.

And here it comes, what we all were waiting for, the `connect` method:

```
class Comp2 extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Total items in cart: {this.props.qty}</h1>
                <h1>Total price of cart :{this.props.price}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps( state ){
    return { qty: state.qty, price:state.price }
}

Comp2 = connect(mapStateToProps)(Comp2);
```

This may be a little bit confusing, so let me explain:
First, we removed everything related to your component's state. We're not using it anymore, cause that's what you wanted right? And also the component is now leaner. And cooler.
But what happened later? well, first we are defining the `mapStateToProps` function. And this is translating redux's state to your components state. This time, we sending every single property from redux's state to your component, but in a bigger app this would not be the case, in a bigger app redux would have the state of everything inside, that could be the cart items, the app theme colors, the user's info etc etc. A lot of things, so inside this function we select only the properties we are interested in getting inside our component.
Now the connect call... we are redefining our component, and it's kinda weird, but I'll try to explain.
`connect` received our `mapStateToProps` method and then our component. And they mated inside `connect` and gave birth to another component, this one is a component that will have the component we defined first as a child, and will always send it the parts of the redux's state we asked for as props.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks a lot. Though I had read about these concepts, your explanation made things a lot clear. However, I am getting state as undefined in the mapStateToProps()? Why is that?

Comment: That may be a problem when you defined the Provider, are you sure you are sending it the `store` as a prop?

Comment: Yup. I did exactly as you mentioned.

Comment: Well, I can't imagine any other problem, if you could paste your new code in codepen, or a gist or somewhere I could give it a glance, I may be able to help you

Comment: Thanks. After placing the createStore() statement after my reducer function, the error is gone. But when I click on the button, nothing seems to happen. I have placed my index.js code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxNPrM#anon-login

Comment: Found your little error. Inside `Comp2` change `{this.props.cartQty}` for `{this.props.qty}`. The same thing for price. Remember that the name they have in the props, comes from the object we returned inside `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 0):

use Provider from react-redux and your store will be available to all your child components

```
                var store = createStore(changeState)
                <Provider store={store}>
                   {child}
                </Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what you need to do, i have given an example with **comp1** Component,
also check this link https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react helps to get more information.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Comp1 extends React.Component {
    increase = () => {
        var action = {
            type: 'INCREMENT',
            qty: 1,
            price: 100
        }
        store.dispatch(action);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.increase}>Increase</button>
        )
    }
}

mapStateToProps = state =>{
  //code to map State to props
}

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
  //code to map dispatch to props
}

export deafult connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Comp1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
import {combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux'; 
//reducer
var initialState = {
    qty: 0,
    price: 0
}

function cart(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            var stateCopy1 = Object.assign({}, state);
            stateCopy1.qty = stateCopy1.qty + action.qty;
            stateCopy1.price = stateCopy1.price + action.price;
            return stateCopy1;
        default:
            return state;

    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({cart});

//Actions
const increase = () => {
        var action = {
            type: 'INCREMENT',
            qty: 1,
            price: 100
        }
    }

let Comp1 = (props) => {
    return (
        <button type="button" onClick={props.increase}>Increase</button>
    )
}
Comp1 = connect(null, {increment})(Comp1);

let Comp2 = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Total items in cart: {props.qty}</h1>
                <h1>Total price of cart :{props.price}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
const mapStateToProps = ({state}) => state.cart
Comp2 = connect(mapStateToProps)(Comp2);

//create store
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Comp1 /><br />
                <Comp2 />
            </Provider >
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

There is for theoretical reference of how to use redux and react-redux based on your example. This should give you idea of how to use both and with little google help you can finish your example I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to develop a project that's more modular as you move along in your learning curve, it will be easier for you.

So set up a `src/index.js`, you already have an `index.js` file I am saying make that your root `index.js` and then refactor it like so:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.scss";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import App from "./components/App";
import reducers from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

So `Provider` is at the top of the hierarchy and having implemented `Provider` you will then be able to utilize the `connect()` function, otherwise you will get an error.

Before we go ahead and implement `connect()` though, lets move down the hierarchy, hierarchy very important in React-Redux.

Provider-> App -> child components.

So next up is `components/App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import Home from "./Home";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

So let's assume that you are wanting to wire up `connect()` to your `Home` component, I don't think you specified, but this is what it would look like:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchLocations } from "../actions";

class Home extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchLocations();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Home List</div>;
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { fetchLocations }
)(Home);
```

You didn't talk much about your action creator or your details about your data so I am just making it about collecting a list of Homes since you have a `Home` component. So above I imported the `connect()` function inside the component and then below I implement it. Pay attention to the fact that I have placed a `null` where your `mapStateToProps` will eventually be. Again, you did not go into details about your state so if I were setting this up for you, `null` is sufficient to get your app working until you are ready to implement `mapStateToProps`, but actions you do need so I created that `fetchLocations` action and implemented inside `connect()`.

For your reducers you can do `reducers/locationsReducer.js`:

```
export default () => {
  return 123;
};
```

And then implement it with your combined reducer like so, `reducers/index.js`:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import locationsReducer from "./locationsReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  locations: locationsReducer
});
```

I believe you now have a functioning React-Redux application and you should be able to take it away from there.