# React error: "could not find the 'store' in the context of ..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I recieve this error message when I run my react app:

> Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Booklist)". Either
>   wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React
>   context provider to  and the corresponding React context
>   consumer to Connect(Booklist) in connect options.

I'm using Create React App and trying to create an app that lists some details.

See code below:

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Booklist from './container/book-list';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Booklist />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**book-list.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Booklist extends Component{  
    renderList(){
        return this.props.books.map((book) =>{
            return(
                <li key={book.title}>{book.title}</li>
            );
        }
        );
    }
    render(){
        return this.props.books.map((book) =>{
            return(
                <ul>{this.renderList()}</ul>
            );
        }
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        books: state.books
    }
}
export default connect (mapStateToProps)(Booklist);
```

**books_reducer.js**

```
export default function(){
    return[
        {title: booke1},
        {title: booke2},
        {title: booke3},
        {title: booke3}
    ]
}
```

**index.js in reducer**

```
import {combineReducers} from redux;
import booksReducer from './books_reducer'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    books: booksReducer
}); 

export default booksReducer;
```

Comment: You're missing the `Provider` on top of your app. Read this explanation I just wrote yesterday about `react-redux` https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411271/1362366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wrapping your app in your store?

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        books: booksReducer
    });
)
<Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use Redux we have to createStore for store all reducers of our app.we combine all Reducers in single component like .

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import BooksReducer from './Books';
import ActiveBookReducer from './activeReducer';
const RootReducer = combineReducers({   
 books : BooksReducer,
 activeBookreducer : ActiveBookReducer 
})
 export default RootReducer;
```

In Above Example I create Two Reducers BookReducer and ActiveBookReducer and I stored both in single Reducer called RootReducer using combineReducer.

1. First import provider and createStore libraries in your index.js file.
2. import your RootReducer in your index.js file.
3. Then take one variable called store and stored RootReducer using createStore library .`const store = createStore(RootReducer);`
4. Then add provider in index.js: `<Provider store = {store}>
   <App />
   </Provider>,`
5. Your code should look like this :

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
   import { createStore } from 'redux';
   import App from './Components/App';
   import RootReducer from './Reducers';
   const store = createStore(RootReducer);
   ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
     <App />
    </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
   );
   ```